# vagrant up - mount error on mavericks

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I just cannot get my vagrant box up and running. This vagrant error makes me sick:

```
$ vagrant up

...

==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => /path/to/folder/of/Vagrantfile
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` /vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` /vagrant /vagrant

...

$ vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Things I've tried:

- sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
- destroying the box and trying again
- restarting

Does anyone else have this problem and got a working solution?

vagrant version is 1.5.4

virtualbox version is 4.3.10 r93012

Content of my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"                #eth1
  # find your correkt interface name by: VBoxManage list bridgedifs"
  config.vm.network :public_network, bridge: "en1: Monitor-Ethernet"      #eth2

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ioapic", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "fsc_box"]
  end

  nfs_setting = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
  config.vm.synced_folder "../../", "/var/www/symfony/current/", id: "symfony" , :nfs => nfs_setting
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline =>
    "if [[ ! -f /apt-get-run ]]; then sudo apt-get update && sudo touch /apt-get-run; fi"

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "site/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "."
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I fixed it via re-installing VirtualBox.